# Java Language - java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550

Tags: java, jdbc, primefaces, glassfish

Good day!

Im using `JSF 2.1` `Primefaces 3.5` `Glassfish 3.2.1`

```
public class UserListProvider extends DBConnectionPool{

    private List sortList;
    private String whereClause;
    private List fieldList;

private void getUserList() {
        List userList = new ArrayList();
        UserBean users = null;
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = null;

        try {
            super.initializeConnection();
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            String sortString = createSortStmt();
            super.cs = super.conn.prepareCall("{call ROCWEB.USERLIST_DATAPROV(?,?,?)}");
            super.cs.setString(1, whereClause);
            super.cs.setString(2, sortString);
            super.cs.registerOutParameter(3, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
            super.cs.execute();

            super.rs = (ResultSet) super.cs.getObject(3);

            //getting the columns
            rsmd = super.rs.getMetaData();
            setFieldList(new ArrayList());
            for (int i = 0; i < rsmd.getColumnCount(); i++) {
                getFieldList().add(rsmd.getColumnLabel(i + 1));
            }

            while (super.rs.next()) {
                users = new UserBean();
                users.setFirstName(rs.getString("firstname"));
                users.setLastName(rs.getString("lastname"));
                users.setPassword(rs.getString("password"));
                users.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                users.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
                users.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));
                users.setUserId(rs.getLong("user_id"));
                userList.add(users);
                users = null;
            }
            conn.commit();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            try {
                if (conn != null) {
                    conn.rollback();
                }
            } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                System.out.println(sqle.getMessage());
            }
        } finally {
            super.closeAll();
        }
        if (userList.isEmpty()) {
            userList.add(new UserBean());
        }
        this.setList(userList);
    }
}
public class DBConnectionPool extends BasePageBean {

public Connection conn;
public ResultSet rs;
public PreparedStatement ps;
public CallableStatement cs;
private String whereClause = "";
private String sortClause = "";
        public void initializeConnection() {
                    try {
                        Context jdbcContext = new InitialContext();
                        DataSource ds = ((DataSource) jdbcContext.lookup("jdbc/rocjndi"));
                        DataSource dsCOP = ((DataSource) jdbcContext.lookup("jdbc/COP"));
                        if(this.conn != null){
                            this.closeAll();
                        }
                        this.conn = null;
                        this.conn = ds.getConnection();
                        this.conn =dsCOP.getConnection();
                        this.conn.setAutoCommit(false);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.out.println(this.getClass() + " - " + e.toString());
                    }
                }

}
```

When using method above(initializeConnection) for connecting to DB using glassfish app server. I got this errors below. If I'm using one datasource it is working but I need two data source. UserListProvider class produce an error below when using two DataSource in initializeConnection method.

> StackTrace;

```
SEVERE: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00201: identifier 'ROCWEB.USERLIST_DATAPROV' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:743)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.doOall8(T4CCallableStatement.java:215)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CCallableStatement.executeForRows(T4CCallableStatement.java:954)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1168)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3285)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3390)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:4223)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.PreparedStatementWrapper.execute(PreparedStatementWrapper.java:508)
    at roc.dao.impl.UserListProvider.getUserList(UserListProvider.java:58)
    at roc.dao.impl.UserListProvider.<init>(UserListProvider.java:33)
    at roc.Login.<init>(Login.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:310)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:188)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
    at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
    at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
    at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:103)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getTarget(AstValue.java:149)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getType(AstValue.java:84)
    at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getType(ValueExpressionImpl.java:200)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getType(TagValueExpression.java:98)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.findImplicitConverter(InputRenderer.java:170)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.findConverter(InputRenderer.java:190)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.InputRenderer.getConvertedValue(InputRenderer.java:196)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1030)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:960)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1233)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:698)
    at javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1172)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at roc.tools.auth.MySecurityFilter.doFilter(MySecurityFilter.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:217)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:655)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:595)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:331)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:231)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$AdapterCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:317)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Please help me to solve this. 



Thank you and More Power!
```

Comment: Could you please post the exception message and the full stacktrace?  Virtually any exception thrown by Oracle JDBC will include the three lines of stacktrace you have shown.

Comment: Hi Sir Luke, here is the full stackTrace..

Comment: Thanks for uploading the stacktrace.  Two further things: can you please edit your question to add all of the exception message, not just `PL/SQL: Statement ignored`.  Secondly, the problem would not seem to be in the code posted.  The error is being thrown from the `load` method of your `UsersTranDAOImpl` class.  Please also edit your question to include the source of this method.

Comment: Also, do you really mean to assign both database connections to the same field, `this.conn`?

Comment: Hi Sir Luke, done in editing my question. Please see updated question of mine. Thank you very much:D

Comment: I want to use two datasources because there is a time that one data source contains no data and just to make sure that there is a data displayed in UI. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the problem is here:

```
                   this.conn = ds.getConnection();
                   this.conn =dsCOP.getConnection();
```

After these two lines, the field `this.conn` contains the 'COP' database connection. The connection to the 'ROC' database that was returned by `ds.getConnection()` has been lost.

I can understand you wanting to use two datasources, but you can't assign them both to the same field!  You will need to create two separate fields, one for each connection, and assign the connections to different fields.  For example:

```
                   this.connROC = ds.getConnection();
                   this.connCOP = dsCOP.getConnection();
```

It seems clear to me from the error message that you have now added that you are using the 'COP' connection to run a query against the 'ROC' database.  Unsurprisingly, this fails, as the `ROCWEB` package doesn't exist in the 'COP' database.

Comment: Hi Sir Luke, I tried your suggestion but its failed. I tried to create   another method for initializing connection, one for ROC and the other is for COP, then it was successfully produce the output that I want to happen. Thank you:)